# iOS push notification not working after changing new http2

Tags: c#, ios, apple-push-notifications, pushsharp

I am using https://github.com/Redth/PushSharp for sending VOIP push notification from my Azure hosted web api and sending VOIP message. Using same certificate for Production and Development and all works fine when debug from local host but when deployed to Azure the connection says timeout.

Do I need to anything unblock port or any changes in apple settings side?